# Data exchange through USB Host Shield

Tags: serial, shields, usb

I have a [Razor IMU](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10736), which communicates through a [USB to Serial Converter](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/USBSerial) with a USB Host Shield mounted on an Arduino Mega 2560.

Even though serial communication can be achieved directly through the Arduino pins, I'm using a Host shield to keep the pins free for other devices. I found the Host Shield Library, which had specific examples for XBOX and PS3 controllers, Bluetooth devices, keyboards and mice etc., but I can't figure out a way to send/receive data to the IMU connected to the shield.

I'm kind of a noob, so be kind. :)

Thanks!

Comment: That really sounds like massive overkill.  You do realise that you have multiple hardware UARTs on the Mega2560?  Also that you can use any pin combination you like using SoftwareSerial to communicate?